# How Best to Convert a Pickled Python Dictionary Using Python shelve Library (bsddb) to a JSON File that has tuple Values for Dictionary Keys

Tags: python, json, shelve, bsddb

I have an application where I need to convert Python shelve pickled dictionary files to JSON files.

```
import ujson, shelve

with open("shelveFile", "r") as sfile:
    shelve_dict=shelve.open(sfile)
    py_dict= dict(shelve_dict)
    with open("jsonfile.json","w") as jsonfile:
        ujson.dump(py_dict, jsonfile)
    with open("jsonfile.json",'r') as readJSONfile:
        ujson.loads(readJSONfile.read())
```

Note: If I use `ujson.load(jsonfile2)` I get a serialization error.

The issue I have: the shelve file uses Python tuple datatypes for some of the dictionary keys. I am able to use `ujson.dump` to save as JSON but when I try to use `ujson.load(jsonfile)` the keys get loaded as strings and not tuples.
Short of using a dictionary comprehension to convert the keys(unsure of that exact syntax), is there a library that would convert a shelve file to a JSON file that I could load back into a Python dictionary object?

When loaded by `ujson.loads(fileobj.read())` method:

```
{"('tuplekey1','tuplekey2')": value,}
```

Should be:

```
{('tuplekey1','tuplekey2'): value,}
```

(please do not down-vote if question is not clear, I will do my best to clarify if needed... I do not post questions here often.)

Comment: One way is using `ast.literal_eval` and evaluate the resulting dict's keys like this example: `{ast.literal_eval(k): v for k, v in my_dict.items()}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tuples cannot be used as dictionary keys when you want to save data with `shelve` or `json`. So in your case string representation of tuples was used instead of actual tuples - `repr(('tuplekey1', 'tuplekey2'))` gives `"('tuplekey1', 'tuplekey2')"`.

So you need additional step to parse strings into tuples. For example, `eval("('tuplekey1', 'tuplekey2')")` or `tuple(val.strip("()' ") for val in a.split(','))`. Of course, you need to know (or recognize) what strings should be parsed into tuples.

The problem may be avoided - data should stored in another manner - another representation of tuples or another structure of data.

Comment: I agree that the data should have been stored in another manner not using tuples for keys, but for now I am just attempting to stop using shelve. Should I parse the JSON manually? I was trying to avoid this.

Comment: The only restriction with Python dictionary keys is that you must use immutable objects.  So in both Python 2.7.15 and Python 3.7 this would be valid: `d = {('testkey1','testkey2'): "myvalune"}
>>> d
{('testkey1', 'testkey2'): 'myvalune'}`.

Comment: Also, though not recommended, you )  _can store_ data in a shelve file with tuples, but you have to pass a fully dictionary (one with tuple keys) as a value to a key in shelve dictionary : `shelve_dict['dict_one'] = {('tkey1', 'tkey2') : "myvalue"`}`

Comment: @Mark Just tried it. Tuples really can be used in `shelve` values. Why not if they can be pickled, yeah? Thanks for the note. As for your data it contains strings not tuples. So you just can't avoid parsing. The problem does not look very hard - several lines of code I guess. Moreover any parsing tool will require you to configure it. And that may be harder than this parsing.

Comment: Yes, I marked your response as the answer.  After looking for a library unsuccessfully where this is built in, I simply parsed the dictionary again after loading it, and used eval to cast the string representation of the tuple to an actual tuple.  It was not very elegant though, because I know that all of the keys in my particular JSON source file are tuples and only one level deep.  It did not apply logic recursively or check the string first to see if it was actually a tuple.  Thank you for posting a solution.